# Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAccessibility'

Tags: swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I did `import UIKit`, but apparently Xcode is still not able to find `UIAccessibility` as mentioned in this [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/230/). Also my os is above 3.0 as required for this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not using Xcode 10 beta with Swift 4.2. So you can't say it that way. You have to call this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post?changes=latest_minor

As you can see, it used to be a global function `UIAccessibilityPostNotification()` taking two parameters.